# Kernel Modules: .o vs .ko

Tags: kernel-modules

It seems that files containing kernel modules are called `.o`, at least that's what I figure when looking at a tutorial like [this one](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/ipmasq-compiling3.1.html). However, on my debian squeeze box, these files seem to be called `.ko`.

Does it depend on the distribution (or verison thereof) whether the files are called `.o` or `.ko`, and are they more or less the same, otherwise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the following answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476990/difference-between-o-and-ko-file):

> The short answer is that the .ko file is your object file linked with
>   some kernel automatically generated data structures that are needed by
>   the kernel.
>
> The .o file is the object file of your modules - the result of
>   compiling your c files. The kernel build system then automatically
>   creates another C file with some data structures describing the kernel
>   module (named your_module_kmod.c), compile this C file into another
>   object file and links your object file and the object file it built
>   together to create the .ko file.
>
> The dynamic linker in the kernel that is in charge of loading kernel
>   modules, expects to find the data structure the kernel put in the kmod
>   object in the .ko file and will not be able to load your kernel module
>   without them.

Also from [that source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476990/difference-between-o-and-ko-file), citing [tldp](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/linuxversions.html): Up to 2.4 kernel versions, it was ".o", and since 2.6, it's ".ko".

Answer (score 4):

It seems an old howto (tutorial), in facts it was written in 2005. When the Linux kernel was 2.4.x the modules had .o extension, while in 2.6 they became .ko